# Tensorflow MirroredStrategy loading the full dataset into GPUs instead of only batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am following the demo code and documentation from [here](https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/):

Where it seems very simple: I create and compile a model under the strategy score MirroredStrategy, which makes a copy of each model graph into each of the given GPUs (4 in this case). This I can see happening and with nvidia-smi I can see some space being allocated for the models in each of the GPUs.

```
# Create a MirroredStrategy.
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy([u'GPU:0', u'GPU:1', u'GPU:2', u'GPU:3'])
print("Number of devices: {}".format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

# Open a strategy scope.
with strategy.scope():
    # Everything that creates variables should be under the strategy scope.
    # In general this is only model construction & `compile()`.
    model = create_and_compile_model()
```

After this step, I can create some random data and train the models using `model.fit()`.  BUT, here is the problem: When calling `model.fit(X_train, Y_train)` , each GPU loads THE FULL dataset first!  This is completely unexpected behavior, as `model.fit()` just pass a data chunk of size "batch_size" to the GPU at a time.

So if my data is a four dimensional tensor of shape `(10,10,10,3)` and I have `N = 16000` samples, when I call:

```
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=16)
```

I get an exhausted resources error on allocating a tensor of size `(16000, 10, 10, 10, 3)`. Instead of only passing a sample of length 16, which runs without any issues when running without the MirroredStrategy.

MirroredStrategy should copy a model into each GPU for the purpose of further dividing the batch into the number of available GPUs, so why is this happening? Is this really the expected behavior of MirroredStrategy?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.distribute.Strategy` should handle the data parallelism and distribution between devices (GPUs) by itself.

All you have to do is define a strategy for instance with

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1", 
    "/gpu:2", "/gpu:3"], cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.ReductionToOneDevice())
```

You have several [options](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/CrossDeviceOps) for cross_device_ops

`tf.distribute.ReductionToOneDevice()`

> This implementation always copies values to one device to reduce them,
> then broadcast reduced values to the destinations. It doesn't support
> efficient batching.

`tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce()`

> It reduces to one GPU along edges in some hierarchy and broadcasts
> back to each GPU along the same path. For the batch API, tensors will
> be repacked or aggregated for more efficient cross-device
> transportation.
>
> This is a reduction created for Nvidia DGX-1 which assumes GPUs
> connects like that on DGX-1 machine. If you have different GPU
> inter-connections, it is likely that it would be slower than
> tf.distribute.ReductionToOneDevice.
>
> For reduces that are not all-reduce, it falls back to
> tf.distribute.ReductionToOneDevice.

```
devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1", 
        "/gpu:2", "/gpu:3"]
```

specifies the list of devices.